# Index array in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to index my array of Dogs in Cosmos DB, but adding the index in indexing policy section from azure portal doesn't change the cost at all. I read their index policy, and yeah they say by default all fields are indexed, and for lists/complex objects, the fields inside are also indexed.. but are they?

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Spatial",
                    "dataType": "Point"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "/Dogs/[]/?",
            "indexes": [
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

Adding the second path, should cover specifically my list of objects, but the change doesn't reflect in the cost of the queries at all.

Is it possible that the change takes time and the index won't reflect instantly, but after a couple of hours? The db is pretty fat, over 100k entries.

**EDIT:** It seems that the index is created bring some improvements for the query(added the path to excluded paths to check the difference, and it's visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the index is created and brings some improvements for the query(added the path to excluded paths to check the difference, and it's visible), so i guess the list is indeed indexed by default.

Answer (score 1):

As you seem to have figured out, the answer is "Yes, they're indexed by default, so you won't see any difference specifically indexing them."

By the by, you can answer your own question on here and accept it. You won't get any points, but I do it fairly often and it's a good idea for a couple reasons. First it shows the question is answered, second it makes the answer clear and makes your question a resource for everybody else who runs into the same problem. Feel free to ignore this answer and make your own.